# Qt - In QGraphicsScene how to put a picture dynamically

Tags: qt

Hai,
 I am trying to create a chess board. Here I want to do a operation like when ever a coin is clicked and dragged, at that time that picture should be copied and be placed in that old position. I don't know in which function I have to do it. When I made it on mouse pressed, then tyhe copy is coming above the original(layer wise). So somebody please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I made it on mouse pressed, then tyhe copy is coming above the original(layer wise).

When you got this far, simply adding a call to myItemCopy->setZValue( -1 ) would place the copy "behind" the original item.

A different approach, and possibly "cleaner", would be to use QDrag and tell Qt how to paint your item during the Drag operation. See Qt's "Drag and Drop Robot" example for reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-dragdroprobot-example.html

Happy coding!
Robin

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this will be to put 2 identical QGraphicsItems for each coin/piece at the same location. The top one will be dragged and moved while the bottom one will stay for the visual cue you want.

Once the top one is dropped to the new location, move the bottom one there too.

Comment: To do the above which are the functions I have to override in QGraphicsScene

Comment: There's no function to override. Just place 2 identical items into the scene at the same location.